# C# Winforms Reports Chart (Devexpress)

Tags: c#, winforms, report, devexpress

[image: A chart of GFR showing a range from 0 to 120 with 0 to 15 marked as Kidney Failure, 15 to 60 marked as Kidney Disease, and 60 to 120 marked as Normal]

I am looking to add this kind of chart (Image attached) to my report which any idea how to do that or which chart control I should use to get this. right now I am using Devexpress but not able to get this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below link to see different chart types available with DevExpress Data Visualization. As I know, it does not have this type of chart, but you can reach out to DevExpress support and ask if the chart control can be customized for your requirement.

[WinForms Data Visualization](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/winforms/chart/gallery.xml)

https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2960/controls-and-libraries/chart-control/series-views/2d-series-views

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no suitable Chart type, you can create a [gauge](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/18225/controls-and-libraries/gauges/concepts/gauge-types/circular-gauges) and insert it in the report as an image.